# Where Can I Alter the Event Additional Participant Wording?

Tags: civievent, registration

What I am trying to do is alter the wording on CiviEvent registration forms. It currently reads:

*How many people are you registering?* [Drop down list]  *(including yourself)*

What I am trying to get it to read is:

*How many people, including yourself, are you registering?* [Drop down list]

Although I have found the line in CRM/Event/Form/Registration/Register.php to amend the bit of text before the drop down list which for me is in line 363; I can not find where the (including yourself) is located. The only reference to the phrase refers to groups partly needing the waitlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check *templates/CRM/Event/Form/Registration/Register.tpl* around line no 71.

Comment: Thank you. I did not think to look there (to be honest I am probably not that clued enough to want to know it is there!)